# How to properly allocate memory using malloc in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

I have  a void pointer and I need to properly allocate memory of correct type. Say:

```
char * array="20080101"
```

Now, I know the value that this char string contains is a long type. Now, I have a void pointer with me:

```
void* pointer;
```

I need to allocate correct amount of memory to it and cast it as a long pointer so it will point to a long value (20080101);

The question is how do we do that? From my research, I know I can allocate it using malloc as:

```
void *pointer=(long*) malloc(sizeof(long) OR sizeof(long)*strlen(array));// what should be the correct parameter.
```

How do we make it point to a value of long type? We have our array in string.

Comment: Cast back to a char pointer and use `atol()` to get the `long int` stored in the string.

Comment: we see that you are a little bit confused, you may not know what really you want. tell us your plan from allocating a pointer to a long that hold a single value. and then maybe we can give a more suitable solution. or at least we can advise you in better way.

Comment: "char string contains is a long type" is incorrect. `array` is a pointer to `char`.

Comment: "How to properly allocate memory using malloc in C" – first, drop the cast. [it only causes harm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, you are a bit confused. First, *A pointer, is a pointer, is a pointer*, not a long and short pointer (anymore) and they are all the same size (generally `8-bytes` on `x86_64` and `4-bytes` on `x86`).

Your `array` points to a null-terminated *string literal*, containing an apparent encoded date of Jan. 1, 2008. The numeric value `20080101` is easily within the size of an `int` or `unsigned` on any system and that is irrelevant to allocating storage for it (unless you are on a `16-bit system).

If you want to convert the `string` to a `long`, you can use `strtol`, e.g.:

```
long myval = strtol (array, NULL, 10);
```

for base `10` conversion. The second parameter (above `NULL`) is actually an `endptr` that on successful conversion returns a pointer to the next character in `array` following the number converted (if the string contains additional characters). You will need to include `<stdlib.h>` to use `strtol`.

As for your cast question, if you have `array` and it is passed as `void`, e.g.

```
long *somefunction (void *value, long *myval, ...)
```

Inside some function, you will need to do two things for conversion:

```
*myval = strtol (value, NULL, 10);

return myval;
```

Or, if you just need to create a pointer to long from `myval`, simply create the pointer:

```
long *lpointer = &myval;
```

**Allocating Storage for array**

When you allocate storage dynamically for any string, you need the length of the string (`+ 1`  for the null-terminator). Here is where you need to understand what `sizeof` will return and what `strlen` will return. If you take `sizeof anypointer`, you do not get the length, you get the pointer size (`8-bytes`, etc..). When you use `sizeof dereferenced pointer` you get the `type size` for the type pointed to (e.g. `sizeof *somelongpointer` will give you the storage size for a `long` on your system)

If you are copying the string, it is better to include `<string.h>` and then:

```
size_t len = strlen (array);
```

Then you are ready to allocate storage:

```
char *mycopy = malloc (len * sizeof *array + 1);
strncpy (mycopy, array, len * sizeof *array + 1);
```

`mycopy` then holds the contents of `array`. Since it was dynamically allocated, you should free it when you no longer need it (e.g. `free (mycopy);`)

If your intent was to create a *pointer to type long* and dynamically allocate storage for the `long`, then you need `sizeof` to determine the size of a long on your system. e.g.

```
long *mylong = malloc (sizeof *mylong);
```

then, (using the same `somefunction` example):

```
*mylong = strtol ((char *)value, NULL, 10);

return mylong;
```

Sorry for the confusion, but that should about cover all cases `:)`.

Comment: Although pointers are not long or short,  I think the OP  may have meant "pointer to long integer" when he said "long pointer".

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification. Moreover, if I need to allocate memory for that string. Should I use only sizeof(the type of the variable) or sizeof(strlen(string)*sizeof(type)). This always confuses me. what should be the correct parameter. My guess is sizeof(type).

Comment: Rule of thumb: Always allocate the size of the thing will are assign to.  i.e `sizeof(long int)`, not `strlen(input)`.  The only time the size of the source data matters is if you are trying to reserve enough memory for an exact copy.

Comment: Minor point: "... numeric value 20080101 is easily within the size of an `int` or `unsigned` on any system".  Many systems of 2015 use 16-bit `int`, which is valid C.

Comment: @AShelly Well, now we are unclear again, do we want to copy the string or dynamically allocate for a long pointer? I'll add that too...

Comment: There is no need to cast a `void*` to any other object pointer type. `void*` already says that this is a pointer to an object of unspecified type, it converts implicitly to any other pointer type.

Comment: Then, it seem to me that you are suggesting to return the address of a local variable? This would be a serious programming error.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to allocate enough memory to hold a long integer, you can do

```
long* value = malloc(sizeof(*value));
```

and then assign to it as @David says:

```
*value = strtol(array, NULL, 10);
```

However, it is usually simpler to use a local variable to hold integers, not allocate them from the heap.

Comment: long* value = malloc(sizeof(value)); is wrong.  Should be sizeof(*value)

Comment: oof. Thanks for the catch. Edited.